# 'AttributeError' while trying to create a console screen using urwid

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, console-application, urwid

code below creates a layout and displays some text in the layout. Next the layout is displayed on the console screen using raw display module from urwid library. (More info on my complete project can be gleaned from questions at [widget advice for a console project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846930/required-widgets-for-displaying-a-1d-console-application) and [urwid for a console project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381319/using-urwid-to-create-a-2d-console-application). My skype help request being [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846113/widget-to-choose-for-1d-urwid-application).) However running the code fails as an AttributeError is raised as described below. On looking at source code for urwid at /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid I see that both main_loop.py and curses_display.py have a draw_screen function with different arguments :
main_loop.py ->    def draw_screen(self):

curses_display.py > def draw_screen(self, (cols, rows), r ):

Do I have to specify which one to use by something like **import draw_screen from specificFile** command ? Or is there anything fundamentally wrong I am looking at the canvas concept ? I can also see that the frame class (**class Frame(BoxWidget):** ) in the file 
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/**container.py** has a render function  (**def render(self, size, focus=False):**)

Error on running code is :

`Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "./yamlUrwidUIPhase6.py", line 104, in <module>

        main()
      File "./yamlUrwidUIPhase6.py", line 98, in main

        form.main()

      File "./yamlUrwidUIPhase6.py", line 51, in main

        self.loop.run()

      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 274, in run

        self.screen.run_wrapper(self._run)

      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 237, in       run_wrapper
    return fn()

      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 285, in _run
    self.draw_screen()

      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 508, in draw_screen

    canvas = self._topmost_widget.render(self.screen_size, focus=True)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'`

The code :

```
import sys  
sys.path.append('./lib')  
import os  
from pprint import pprint  
import random  
import urwid  
ui=urwid.raw_display.Screen()


class FormDisplay(object):

    def __init__(self):
        global ui
        self.ui = ui
        self.palette = self.ui.register_palette([
            ('Field', 'dark green, bold', 'black'), # information fields, Search: etc.
            ('Info', 'dark green', 'black'), # information in fields
            ('Bg', 'black', 'black'), # screen background
            ('InfoFooterText', 'white', 'dark blue'), # footer text
            ('InfoFooterHotkey', 'dark cyan, bold', 'dark blue'), # hotkeys in footer text
            ('InfoFooter', 'black', 'dark blue'),  # footer background
            ('InfoHeaderText', 'white, bold', 'dark blue'), # header text
            ('InfoHeader', 'black', 'dark blue'), # header background
            ('BigText', RandomColor(), 'black'), # main menu banner text
            ('GeneralInfo', 'brown', 'black'), # main menu text
            ('LastModifiedField', 'dark cyan, bold', 'black'), # Last modified:
            ('LastModifiedDate', 'dark cyan', 'black'), # info in Last modified:
            ('PopupMessageText', 'black', 'dark cyan'), # popup message text
            ('PopupMessageBg', 'black', 'dark cyan'), # popup message background
            ('SearchBoxHeaderText', 'light gray, bold', 'dark cyan'), # field names in the search box
            ('SearchBoxHeaderBg', 'black', 'dark cyan'), # field name background in the search box
            ('OnFocusBg', 'white', 'dark magenta') # background when a widget is focused
           ])
        urwid.set_encoding('utf8')

    def main(self):
        global ui
        #self.view = ui.run_wrapper(formLayout)
        self.ui.start()
        self.view = formLayout()

        self.loop = urwid.MainLoop(self.view, self.palette, unhandled_input=self.unhandled_input)
        self.loop.run()

    def unhandled_input(self, key):
        if key == 'f8':
          quit()
          return


def formLayout():
    global ui
    text1 = urwid.Text("Urwid 3DS Application program - F8 exits.")
    text2 = urwid.Text("One mission accomplished")

    textH = urwid.Text("topmost Pile text")
    cols = urwid.Columns([text1,text2])
    pile = urwid.Pile([textH,cols])
    fill = urwid.Filler(pile)

    textT  = urwid.Text("Display") 

    textSH = urwid.Text("Pile text in Frame")
    textF = urwid.Text("Good progress !")

    frame = urwid.Frame(fill,header=urwid.Pile([textT,textSH]),footer=textF)
    dim = ui.get_cols_rows()
    #ui is treated as global handle for all functions, either belonging
    #to any class or standalone functions such as formLayout
    #need to check if screen has been started
    if not ui._started:
        print("Screen has not been started, so no use of rendering.Thus return :-( ")
        return

    ui.draw_screen(dim, frame.render(dim, True))
    return

def RandomColor():
    '''Pick a random color for the main menu text'''
    listOfColors = ['dark red', 'dark green', 'brown', 'dark blue',
                    'dark magenta', 'dark cyan', 'light gray',
                    'dark gray', 'light red', 'light green', 'yellow',
                    'light blue', 'light magenta', 'light cyan', 'default']
    color = listOfColors[random.randint(0, 14)]
    return color

def main():
    form = FormDisplay()
    form.main()

########################################
##### MAIN ENTRY POINT
########################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't want to change the function formLayout as I intend to add more to this basic code framework, where in another function will be added that repeatedly calls formLayout to keep updating the screen based on reading values from a yml file. I already have a separate code that deals with reading the yaml file and extracting ordered dictionaries out it. After figuring out how to get basic urwid console working, I can move on to integrating both to create my final application.

Comment: Can you run `dir` on canvas, and see what you get? Python REPL ofc.

Comment: I did not understand what running dir on a canvas means ? i know that dir is a command , where do you want me to run it ?

Comment: Open up your python repl. Import your classes and run a `dir` on the `frame` class. See if render is present. Then run `dir` as in `dir()` on `widget` to see if `render` is really there.

Comment: I did this `>>> dir()     
    ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'readline', 'rlcompleter']  
            >>> import urwid      
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'readline', 'rlcompleter', 'urwid']  
>>> dir() urwid  
  File "<stdin>", line 1  
    dir() urwid  
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  
>>> dir() frame  
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    dir() frame
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Run this: `dir(urwind)`. See what comes up.

Comment: `>>> dir(urwid)
['ANY', 'AttrMap', 'AttrMapError', 'AttrSpec', 'AttrSpecError', 'AttrWrap', 'BLACK', 'BOTTOM', 'BOX', 'BROWN', 'BarGraph', 'BarGraphError', 'BarGraphMeta', 'BaseScreen', 'BigText', 'BlankCanvas', 'BoxAdapter', 'BoxAdapterError', 'BoxWidget', 'Button', 'CENTER', 'CLIP', 'Canvas', 'CanvasCache', 'CanvasCombine', 'CanvasError', .....] ` In this list I can see canvas. what next ?

Comment: Okay, now try to see if when you run it on canvas, if you can get a `render` function. If thats the case, then there is something wrong with the library, otherwise, you might be just importing it wrong.

Comment: render doesn't seem to be there - > `>>> import Canvas
>>> dir()
['Canvas', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'readline', 'rlcompleter', 'urwid']
>>> dir(Canvas)
['Arc', 'Bitmap', 'Canvas', 'CanvasItem', 'CanvasText', 'Group', 'ImageItem', 'Line', 'Oval', 'Polygon', 'Rectangle', 'Window', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_cnfmerge', '_flatten']
`

Comment: but why do we look for render in canvas class when i am using frame.render ?

Comment: Well, can you tell me what is on line 51 again in your script?

Comment: line 51 is this :  `self.loop.run()`

Comment: Take a look @ this then, `canvas = self._topmost_widget.render(self.screen_size, focus=True)`, that is giving you the problem, what class is `_topmost_widget` in this casE?

Answer (score 0):

The Attribute Error was removed by adding following lines in the code as shown at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910768/command-prompt-messed-up-after-running-a-python-program).

line 1 :
`self.loop.widget = self.view` in `main` of class FormDisplay

line 2 :
doing a `return Frame` instead of `return` in the function formLayout()

line 3 :
added lines to handle key presses in `unhandled_input` function